# /tmp mounting options as tmpfs: Compatibility & Security

Tags: permissions, mount, ssd, tmpfs

Having a SSD - it is recommended to mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs`.

Examples:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/550589/best-way-to-mount-tmp-in-fstab
- https://yktoo.com/en/blog/post/233
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount

The mounting options are different in each example - why???

The default Ubuntu 16 installation sets the mounting options for root (`/`) as (from `/etc/mtab`):

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

Ergo all other options - as suggested in the examples/links - shouldn't be applied.
Some of the mounting options in the various examples on the web are:

```
defaults,noatime,mode=1777
```

or:

```
defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=512M
```

But:

- Having `noatime` feels useless because that the data is stored in RAM which is fast anyway.
- Why `nosuid,nodev,noexec` ?
  How do they know whether softwares are dependent on certain options or not?

---

I think it is best to stick with the default permissions that the installation applied, meaning:

```
rw,relatime,mode=1777,uid=0,gid=0
```

In order to ensure proper operation of various softwares:

- The permissions are 1777 because that the default permissions for `/tmp` are also `drwxrwxrwt` (see `stat -c "%a %n" /tmp`).
- The `uid` and `gid` are `root` because that `/tmp` has the same.

Is there something which I'm missing here?

Comment: drwxrwxrwt is 1777, not 0776. It's admittedly a little confusing because `ls` fits 12 permission bits into 9 character positions.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick True. The documentation for that isn't good. I've seen [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-chmod-numeric-permissions-notation-command/) source. Is there a difference between `1776` and `1777` ?

Comment: 1776 doesn't have x permission for other. That's not good for a public directory like /tmp - it would mean users who aren't root and aren't in group 0 cannot access any file in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Before *systemd*, the standard way to activate *tmpfs* on */tmp* was to activate it in `/etc/default/tmpfs` and set `RAMTMP=yes` (even if almost everyone was editing /etc/fstab). This way you can see what are the default options. On my Devuan Ascii the mounting options are:

```
$ mount -l | grep "/tmp"
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3293980k)
```

size defaults to 20% physical memory + swap.

So I guess you could not go wrong using the same options in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

> it is recommended to mount /tmp as tmpfs

No.

You *may* mount a tmpfs device at /tmp if you don't care about losing the files on reboot (tmpfs is implemented in memory).

> Ergo all other options - as suggested in the examples/links - shouldn't be applied.

Eh? You don't want these options? Or you think that the OS will ignore them? In the case of the former, choose the options you do want - they WILL be honoured / they are NOT inherited.

> Having noatime feels useless

Yes, having atime or relatime has negligible cost here.

> Why nosuid,nodev,noexec ?

Because these can be exploited in /tmp. However the use of the sticky bit also provides mitigation of (all?) attacks using these vectors.

> rw,relatime,mode=1777,uid=0,gid=0

rw - well that's kinda useful for a temporary filesystem - but it is also the DEFAULT behaviour so you don't need to explicit state this.

relatime - up to you - but again its the default.

mode=1777,uid=0,gid=0 - if, at mount time, your /tmp is not owned by root and world writeable, with the group sticky bit set, then its probably too late to plug those holes.